# Export FASTREPORT print as PDF

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, pdf, fastreport

Is there anyone knows how to get PDF prints from "fast report"? (.NET)

```
report1.Export(frxPDFExport1);
```

that line doesn't work, ?

Comment: Did you get any exception or error message?

Comment: says "it doesn't exist in current contex"?  May I install a tool?

Comment: Why you question have javascript tag? how does it ralated?

Answer (score 9):

Hi here is the answer how to export to pdf.

```
using FastReport.Export.Pdf;

 report1.Prepare();
              PDFExport pdf = new PDFExport();
              report1.Export(pdf, "c:\\ExportedPDF.pdf");
```

That's it :) to export to other formats you need to create appropriate ExportBase object. 
Also if your report have forms - then user must click ok first and only then it will create pdf because of Prepare method.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code :

```
using FastReport.Export.Pdf;
report1.Prepare();
PDFExport pdf = new PDFExport();
pdf.FileName = "c:\\YourPDF.pdf"
report1.Export(pdf);
```